# Hyper-V prevented starting virtual machine because it is prepared for failover

Tags: hyper-v

I got this error while I was using Hyper-V Replica

Hyper-V prevented starting virtual machine because it is prepared for failover.

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 2):

As per google at

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2157019-replication-with-hyperv-won-t-start

If you want to start the replica, you need to do a planned failover. That will shut down the primary VM, send over a final replication, and if you tell it to, start the replica and reverse replication.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configure the virtual switch manager and network connections correctly on your replica server before you try running a planned failover. The machine needs to be able to come up first. Turn off your primary and complete the configuration first, then have another go at it.